# Printing multiple variables in single printf() statement

Tags: c, printf

What I have so far:

```
printf("Entered string is %c", string, "with length %d", i,
"and ID number is %s", number, "with length %d", j);
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
Entered string is 4
```

Comment: Kindly , see the link which i mentioned earlier. Hope you understand .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For string use `%s` instead of `%c`  and If your Id number is integer use `%d` 
  instead of `%s`

```
 printf("Entered string is %s with length %d and
     ID number is %s with length %d",string,i, number, j);
```